# How to customize the drupal filter based only on user Role Drupal

Tags: search, drupal-search

problem:

How to customize the default search that it will only display based on user role and it's page created? Is there any available module for this or do I have to write hook function for this?

I’m using drupal 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Search configuration](http://drupal.org/project/search_config) module may do what you're looking for.